# UIViewController inside UINavigationController Jumps down when application returns from background

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uiapplication

When my app returns from background, the `UIViewController` jumps down the height of the `UINavigationBar` (44 pixels).

Everything is being controlled through a story board using push segues.

Even when I `NSLog` the frame of both the view controller and the navigation controller after the "jump",  using `NSStringFromCGRect`, they both show (0,0,320,480) as their frame, even though its clearly not the case.

**Before:**

[image]

**After returning from background:**

[image]

Comment: Do you change the top bar translucency in your code, or in interface builder ?

Comment: The view size remains that of the full screen in iOS7, regardless of whether the navigation bar is showing or not.

Comment: I do change the top bar translucency on viewWillAppear of the view controller.  2 seconds after I wrote the question I noticed this was the problem, and 2 seconds later @erhnby posted the same answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this code for hide navigation bar in YourViewController

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:YES];
    [self.navigationController.navigationBar setHidden:YES];
}
```